# C++ Equals Operator

Tags: c++, equals-operator

I have the following equals operator:

```
  bool operator==(const Duration& x, const Duration& y){
        return ( x.hrs == y.hrs, x.mins == y.mins, x.secs == y.secs );
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
 bool operator==(const Duration& x, const Duration& y){
        return ( (x.hrs == y.hrs) && (x.mins == y.mins) && (x.secs == y.secs) );
    }
```

In my main method I have:

```
  //Arbitrary Durations - Testing
    Duration dTest0 (01,45,12);
    Duration dTest1 (01,35,45);
    Duration dTest2 (01,35,45);
    Duration dTest3 (01,25,05);

    if ( dTest0 == dTest1 ){
        cout<< "broken" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<< "working" << endl;
        }
```

My program keeps outputting "broken" which suggests that dTest0 and dTest1 are infact equal... Where am I going wrong?

Additional: If I use `x.getHours == y.getHours...` It puts a red line under the `"."` and says: 'Error: a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function`.

Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: The second version is the correct one and it should work. Can you post a minimal example on ideone.com ?

Comment: The error message is because if `getHours` is a method, you have to have `x.getHours()`.

Comment: Its working now with `x.getHours()` I was missing the `()`. I didn't realise they were required. Im a newbie and self studying from a book which doesnt seem to mention that. Thanks for your time @LuchianGrigore

Comment: @qwertyRocker Just a heads up, `()` is the "function call" operator and is required to invoke a function. The only time it isn't required is when storing the value of the function in a pointer (`durFunc = Duration::getHours;`). So, whenever you need to invoke (execute, run, perform, however you want to look at it) a function make sure to include the `()` function operator.

Comment: @izuriel Ok, thats a good explaination, thanks so much. I'm glad i asked this question. Everything is much clearer now. Thanks again :D

Comment: This has nothing to do with the problem, but in the second version you don't need any of the parentheses. Of course, you may need to add some other parentheses if some of these things are supposed to be function calls.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first implementation will only return true if `x.secs == y.secs`. The results of the first two comparisons will be discarded. The `,` operator evaluates to the value of its second operand, which in this case boils down to just `x.secs == y.secs`.

The second one, however, is correct. If it is not working, then you must be setting the values of `hrs`, `mins`, and `secs` incorrectly in the constructor of `Duration`.

The problem that you have with `getHours` is that you need to call it. It is a member function after all. So do `x.getHours()` instead of `x.getHours`.

Comment: This was my problem (forgot to add `()` to it). Thank you for explaining it. I will mark correct as soon as it will allow me. Cheers.

Comment: @qwertyRocker, So what was the problem with the false positives?

Comment: @chris The problem was exactly as described above by Sftrabbit. I was using `x.sec` which always returned true and when i tried `x.getSecs`it wouldnt compile. I was missing the `()` and I should of been using `x.getSecs()`. Since changing them to the correct method name, its working as it should :D

Comment: @qwertyRocker, Why wan't `x.secs` working, though? Is it not the same value as returned by `getSecs()`?

Answer (score 6):

The first one is wrong.  `,` does not work that way.

The second one is correct, assuming `Duration` is reasonable.

You may have a bug in your `Duration` constructor.  I'd even think it is likely.